# Requests response is leaving some data behind

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape some data from google using requests but it can't return everything from the webpage.

**Code:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Mobile Safari/537.36'}
url = 'https://www.google.com/search?num=50&q="potato+is+good"'

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

for idx, val in enumerate(soup.find_all('em'), 1):
    print('{} = {}'.format(idx, val))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
1 = <em>potato is good</em>
2 = <em>potato is good</em>
3 = <em>potato is good</em>
4 = <em>Potato is good</em>
5 = <em>potato is good</em>
6 = <em>potato is good</em>
7 = <em>Potato is good</em>
8 = <em>potato is good</em>
9 = <em>potato is good</em>
10 = <em>potato is good</em>
11 = <em>potato.is.good</em>
```

It showed only 11 results but there are 35+ results when I performed the search manually on google.

What could be possibly wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be returning results as though you're searching via a mobile device? 
I just tried and only get 11 results on the first page of Google on my iPhone. Maybe a different user agent, like the below, would do the trick?

`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36`

## EDIT:

#### I ran this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'}
url = 'https://www.google.com/search?num=50&q="potato+is+good"'

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

for idx, val in enumerate(soup.find_all('em'), 1):
    print('{} = {}'.format(idx, val))
```

#### And got:

```
1 = <em>potato is good</em>
2 = <em>potato is good</em>
3 = <em>potato is good</em>
4 = <em>potato is good</em>
5 = <em>potatoÔÇØ is good</em>
6 = <em>potato is good</em>
7 = <em>potato-is good</em>
8 = <em>potato is good</em>
9 = <em>Potato is good</em>
10 = <em>potato is good</em>
11 = <em>potato is good</em>
12 = <em>potato is good</em>
13 = <em>potato is good</em>
14 = <em>potato is good</em>
15 = <em>potato is good</em>
16 = <em>potato is good</em>
17 = <em>Potato is good</em>
18 = <em>potato is good</em>
19 = <em>potato is good</em>
20 = <em>potato is good</em>
21 = <em>potato is good</em>
22 = <em>potato is good</em>
23 = <em>potato is good</em>
24 = <em>potato is good</em>
25 = <em>potato is good</em>
26 = <em>potato is good</em>
27 = <em>potato is good</em>
28 = <em>potato is good</em>
29 = <em>potato is good</em>
30 = <em>potato is good</em>
31 = <em>potato is good</em>
32 = <em>potato is good</em>
33 = <em>potato is good</em>
34 = <em>potato is good</em>
35 = <em>potato is good</em>
36 = <em>potato is good</em>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Check what's your `user-agent`](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent). Learn more about [HTTP request headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Request_header).

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Scrape-Title-Description-Linkpythonbs4#bs4_results.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
  "q": "samurai cop what does katana mean",
  "gl": "us",
  "hl": "en",
}

html = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

for result in soup.select('.tF2Cxc'):
  title = result.select_one('.DKV0Md').text
  link = result.select_one('.yuRUbf a')['href']
  print(f'{title}\n{link}\n')

-------
'''
Samurai Cop - He speaks fluent Japanese - YouTube
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=paTW3wOyIYw

Samurai Cop - What does "katana" mean? - Quotes.net
https://www.quotes.net/mquote/1060647

Samurai Cop (1991) - Mathew Karedas as Joe Marshall - IMDb
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0130236/characters/nm0360481
...
...
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using [Google Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that you don't need to figure out why certain things don't work as expected, or to code everything from scratch and maintain it over time, instead you only need to iterate over structured JSON and get the data you want.

Code to integrate:

```py
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
    "engine": "google",
    "q": "samurai cop what does katana mean",
    "hl": "en",
    "gl": "in",
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for result in results["organic_results"]:
  print(result['title'])
  print(result['link'])
  print()

------
'''
Samurai Cop - He speaks fluent Japanese - YouTube
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=paTW3wOyIYw

Samurai Cop - What does "katana" mean? - Quotes.net
https://www.quotes.net/mquote/1060647
...
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.